# Determine if record has children in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I am having at hierarchical table with the structure
ID, Name, FK_ID, Sortkey

Fetching the data in LINQ to SQL is straight forward:

```
var list = from ls in db.myTable
           where ls.FK_ID == levelId
           orderby ls.sortkey ascending
           select ls;
```

And I can traverse down the tree by linking to the next levelId.

But what I can't figure out, if there is a way in LINQ, to check if there is any children

I could probably build a view, that added a flag to each record, but I would rather do this in LINQ, if possible.

What would even be the best practice for adding such a flag in SQL?

My idea on checking each record, is not the most performance friendly solution.

Comment: Is this a method you're writing? i.e. pass in the levelID as a parameter and check to see if that Level has any children? Or do you just want all Levels that have children?

Comment: @FizzBuzz right now I am only listing the data in a GridView, and then hyperlinking on the name column to the next level. What I was looking for was another column with a flag that indicates if that record had any children (boolean)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have set up the foreign key correctly, should you not have the 1 to Many mapping properties?

i.e. You could write

```
var listWithChildren = list.Where(l => l.Children.Any());
```

or going the other direction

```
var listWithParent = list.Where(l => l.FK_ID != null);
```

or using the query expression instead of fluent

```
var listWithChildren = from item in list
                       where item.Children.Any()
                       select item;
```

as you asked in your comments for a boolean flag, you could do

```
var updatedList = from item in list
                  select new 
                  {
                    Item = item,
                    HasChildren = item.Children.Any()
                  };
```

Comment: I can't seem to get Children.Any to work, it doesn't seems that the keyword is supported, so I must be missing something.
But I have a couple of workarounds. Either use SQL to create the data, or iterate over my Linq object and put it into a POCO. I can do a kind of item.myTable.Count()

Comment: You could replace the .Any() with .Count() > 0

Comment: Here is the MSDN link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386935.aspx

Comment: Actually it is the keyword Children I can't get to work.
Apparently there must be something wrong with my dbml model somewhere. I can se the Item.Items which is the child, and Item.Item1 which is the father, but no keyword like Children...

Comment: Children was just a name for the mapping collection. It's not a .NET keyword. So yes, if you replaced my code above with item.Items.Any() it should work.

Comment: Feeling a bit dumb here, can see why color encoding isnt't always a good idea ;) #misinterpretation